# Randomly Named Files appearing in Hidden folders (virus?)

Tags: windows-10, virus, malware, ransomware

I have random hidden folders containing files with randomly generated file names I haven't created appearing in my Documents Folder (which is synced to OneDrive).

e.g. OneDrive\Documents\2016-11-08 22-19-1 working138

> common_mild_librarian_certain.rtf
>
> cross.chairs.mdb
>
> directeddemonstratedgerman.pem
>
> friends_legs.doc
>
> grammaticalstainedexcited.xls
>
> knew-agree-buying-square.jpg
>
> lipstick beast.xlsx
>
> mostsidesmakebrothers.sql
>
> nonefewer.txt
>
> spring.beginning.docx

and in 
OneDrive\Documents\Tmirror198

> alec-cocktail-law.pem
>
> barrel savage students exclusively.rtf
>
> building except character.txt
>
> confront stars calling carefully.docx
>
> diverse concrete hanging.sql
>
> markets-fall-asked-herself.xls
>
> organic_heads.doc
>
> pipeexplicit.mdb
>
> satisfaction-altered-empty.xlsx
>
> viewed.hesitate.jpg

Anybody knows why is this happening? I tried scanning with malwarebytes and windows defender but nothing came up.
I also have CyberReason RansomFree installed all along and that didn't detect anything.

> Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem
>   Usage
>   ========================= ======== ================ =========== ============ System Idle Process              0 Services                   0          8 K System                           4 Services
>   0        136 K smss.exe                       416 Services
>   0        920 K csrss.exe                      616 Services
>   0      4,312 K wininit.exe                    712 Services
>   0      4,248 K csrss.exe                      720 Console
>   1      5,536 K services.exe                   788 Services
>   0      7,940 K lsass.exe                      804 Services
>   0     13,632 K svchost.exe                    924 Services
>   0        792 K WUDFHost.exe                   948 Services
>   0      6,132 K fontdrvhost.exe                968 Services
>   0        948 K svchost.exe                    992 Services
>   0     21,076 K WUDFHost.exe                   480 Services
>   0      4,096 K svchost.exe                    784 Services
>   0     12,712 K svchost.exe                   1060 Services
>   0      3,404 K winlogon.exe                  1164 Console
>   1      3,992 K fontdrvhost.exe               1220 Console
>   1     11,820 K svchost.exe                   1332 Services
>   0      5,580 K dwm.exe                       1372 Console
>   1     67,796 K svchost.exe                   1420 Services
>   0      3,812 K svchost.exe                   1428 Services
>   0      4,620 K svchost.exe                   1528 Services
>   0      1,936 K svchost.exe                   1600 Services
>   0      3,408 K svchost.exe                   1644 Services
>   0      3,664 K svchost.exe                   1656 Services
>   0      2,668 K svchost.exe                   1688 Services
>   0     12,168 K ASCService.exe                1760 Services
>   0      9,436 K svchost.exe                   1784 Services
>   0      2,652 K svchost.exe                   1828 Services
>   0      4,864 K svchost.exe                   1880 Services
>   0      7,088 K WUDFHost.exe                   708 Services
>   0      2,692 K svchost.exe                   2108 Services
>   0      3,756 K svchost.exe                   2168 Services
>   0      5,468 K svchost.exe                   2292 Services
>   0      7,904 K FBAgent.exe                   2392 Services
>   0      3,432 K svchost.exe                   2428 Services
>   0      5,336 K svchost.exe                   2436 Services
>   0      3,616 K svchost.exe                   2444 Services
>   0      1,264 K svchost.exe                   2488 Services
>   0      5,984 K Memory Compression            2680 Services
>   0    345,576 K svchost.exe                   2708 Services
>   0      4,208 K svchost.exe                   2720 Services
>   0      9,164 K igfxCUIService.exe            2808 Services
>   0      2,012 K svchost.exe                   2844 Services
>   0      4,024 K svchost.exe                   2944 Services
>   0      4,024 K svchost.exe                   3048 Services
>   0      3,612 K svchost.exe                   2604 Services
>   0      8,652 K svchost.exe                   3132 Services
>   0      3,244 K svchost.exe                   3160 Services
>   0      9,736 K svchost.exe                   3252 Services
>   0      2,552 K svchost.exe                   3260 Services
>   0      8,380 K svchost.exe                   3368 Services
>   0     11,612 K svchost.exe                   3420 Services
>   0      6,440 K AsLdrSrv.exe                  3428 Services
>   0      1,652 K wlanext.exe                   3448 Services
>   0      6,000 K conhost.exe                   3464 Services
>   0      1,148 K GFNEXSrv.exe                  3516 Services
>   0        820 K spoolsv.exe                   3572 Services
>   0      4,164 K svchost.exe                   3644 Services
>   0      2,604 K svchost.exe                   3732 Services
>   0     14,216 K svchost.exe                   3768 Services
>   0      2,508 K svchost.exe                   3808 Services
>   0      3,768 K AppleMobileDeviceService.     4176 Services
>   0      2,984 K AdAppMgrSvc.exe               4184 Services
>   0      7,780 K armsvc.exe                    4192 Services
>   0      1,512 K AsHidSrv.exe                  4200 Services
>   0      1,728 K SoftKBService.exe             4220 Services
>   0      3,868 K AsusWSWinService.exe          4232 Services
>   0      4,364 K mDNSResponder.exe             4244 Services
>   0      2,936 K svchost.exe                   4256 Services
>   0      4,860 K svchost.exe                   4264 Services
>   0     10,256 K IntelCpHDCPSvc.exe            4276 Services
>   0      1,644 K CTService.exe                 4296 Services
>   0     15,244 K CybereasonRansomFreeServi     4316 Services
>   0    144,092 K svchost.exe                   4344 Services
>   0     37,700 K esif_uf.exe                   4368 Services
>   0      1,232 K svchost.exe                   4376 Services
>   0     20,264 K EvtEng.exe                    4412 Services
>   0      7,808 K GarminService.exe             4428 Services
>   0     13,016 K ibtsiva.exe                   4500 Services
>   0      1,900 K IUService.exe                 4512 Services
>   0      3,940 K svchost.exe                   4556 Services
>   0     10,028 K SSDToolService.exe            4652 Services
>   0      2,744 K mitsijm.exe                   4672 Services
>   0      1,452 K svchost.exe                   4684 Services
>   0      3,580 K sqlservr.exe                  4712 Services
>   0     32,100 K svchost.exe                   4764 Services
>   0      1,004 K RegSrvc.exe                   4780 Services
>   0      3,300 K remotesolverdispatcherser     4800 Services
>   0      1,000 K SecurityHealthService.exe     4816 Services
>   0     13,972 K sqlbrowser.exe                4916 Services
>   0      1,000 K sqlwriter.exe                 4924 Services
>   0      1,360 K SurSvc.exe                    4940 Services
>   0      4,004 K DCNTranProc.exe               4972 Services
>   0      1,680 K svchost.exe                   5008 Services
>   0     13,948 K ZeroConfigService.exe         5016 Services
>   0     10,448 K svchost.exe                   5040 Services
>   0     25,388 K ASUSKBLock.exe                5288 Services
>   0     12,156 K dispatcher.exe                5348 Services
>   0      1,060 K conhost.exe                   5356 Services
>   0      1,480 K svchost.exe                   5912 Services
>   0      8,188 K svchost.exe                   6492 Services
>   0      1,488 K WmiPrvSE.exe                  7044 Services
>   0      7,704 K unsecapp.exe                  7224 Services
>   0      2,384 K IntelCpHeciSvc.exe            7288 Services
>   0      4,212 K OfficeClickToRun.exe          9080 Services
>   0     22,220 K svchost.exe                   4000 Services
>   0      3,500 K svchost.exe                   8668 Services
>   0      4,832 K svchost.exe                   9164 Services
>   0      2,452 K HControl.exe                  6904 Console
>   1      3,876 K esif_assist_64.exe            6660 Console
>   1      1,168 K sihost.exe                    2460 Console
>   1     22,500 K svchost.exe                   2532 Console
>   1     12,360 K svchost.exe                   8764 Console
>   1     26,320 K svchost.exe                   9060 Services
>   0     13,556 K ACMON.exe                     3540 Console
>   1      2,360 K taskhostw.exe                 6584 Console
>   1      8,672 K svchost.exe                   4272 Services
>   0      3,316 K Monitor.exe                   8920 Console
>   1     14,204 K CybereasonRansomFree.exe      9476 Console
>   1     14,952 K AsPatchTouchPanel64.exe       9372 Console
>   1      1,072 K DMedia.exe                     960 Console
>   1      2,600 K ATKOSD2.exe                   1128 Console
>   1      7,388 K AppVShNotify.exe              9368 Console
>   1      1,148 K PresentationFontCache.exe     2672 Services
>   0      5,384 K svchost.exe                  10296 Services
>   0      2,620 K svchost.exe                  10316 Console
>   1     34,980 K igfxEM.exe                   10712 Console
>   1      5,056 K RuntimeBroker.exe            12048 Console
>   1     33,776 K SpeechRuntime.exe            12236 Console
>   1     13,516 K ctfmon.exe                   10924 Console
>   1     23,200 K TabTip.exe                   10780 Console
>   1     10,208 K SettingSyncHost.exe           5768 Console
>   1      6,416 K svchost.exe                  12396 Services
>   0     10,840 K TabTip32.exe                 12456 Console
>   1      1,328 K svchost.exe                  12872 Services
>   0     11,172 K svchost.exe                  13608 Services
>   0     12,636 K MSASCuiL.exe                   744 Console
>   1      3,248 K iTunesHelper.exe             14436 Console
>   1      3,576 K OneDrive.exe                 14560 Console
>   1     63,476 K OneDrive.exe                 14652 Console
>   1     75,496 K Miro.exe                     14832 Console
>   1     34,040 K iPodService.exe              14920 Services
>   0      2,632 K RAVBg64.exe                   4824 Console
>   1      2,156 K iCloudServices.exe           11884 Console
>   1     17,908 K APSDaemon.exe                 9596 Console
>   1      8,852 K jusched.exe                  12128 Console
>   1      6,220 K ONENOTEM.EXE                  7184 Console
>   1      2,768 K GoogleCrashHandler.exe        9188 Services
>   0        516 K ASCTray.exe                  11428 Console
>   1     10,160 K InputPersonalization.exe      4932 Console
>   1      3,968 K Miro_Downloader.exe          10312 Console
>   1      6,864 K Miro_Helper.exe              15964 Console
>   1      4,768 K conhost.exe                  16088 Console
>   1      1,984 K GoogleCrashHandler64.exe      4460 Services
>   0        308 K jhi_service.exe              16636 Services
>   0      1,240 K LMS.exe                      12852 Services
>   0      2,664 K svchost.exe                  13708 Services
>   0      4,004 K XtuService.exe               11180 Services
>   0      5,940 K ICCProxy.exe                 17084 Services
>   0      1,496 K SkypeHost.exe                16416 Console
>   1     24,256 K RuntimeBroker.exe            17324 Console
>   1     10,476 K MsMpEng.exe                   2628 Services
>   0    199,620 K NisSrv.exe                   15224 Services
>   0     11,480 K SearchIndexer.exe            16888 Services
>   0     40,864 K ApplicationFrameHost.exe      1028 Console
>   1     44,600 K WinStore.App.exe             10624 Console
>   1        416 K RuntimeBroker.exe            15468 Console
>   1      9,756 K isa.exe                        152 Services
>   0     11,880 K UninstallMonitor.exe         12216 Console
>   1     13,780 K svchost.exe                  10728 Services
>   0      3,648 K ASC.exe                      13356 Console
>   1      7,996 K svchost.exe                  23164 Services
>   0      3,264 K svchost.exe                  22332 Services
>   0     10,212 K dllhost.exe                  19032 Console
>   1      6,288 K LiveUpdate.exe               17956 Console
>   1     25,776 K Microsoft.Photos.exe         17224 Console
>   1     20,924 K RuntimeBroker.exe            22436 Console
>   1     15,432 K HxTsr.exe                     7888 Console
>   1     26,252 K RuntimeBroker.exe            20100 Console
>   1      6,664 K HxCalendarAppImm.exe         18800 Console
>   1        292 K svchost.exe                  21332 Services
>   0      6,612 K svchost.exe                  17472 Services
>   0      5,776 K SETUP.EXE                    13988 Console
>   1      2,920 K dllhost.exe                   2344 Services
>   0      4,480 K Gaseq.exe                     3628 Console
>   1     14,360 K WINWORD.EXE                  23284 Console
>   1    224,364 K explorer.exe                  1480 Console
>   1    133,252 K RemindersServer.exe          24864 Console
>   1     26,536 K SearchUI.exe                  6216 Console
>   1    154,016 K RuntimeBroker.exe            23196 Console
>   1     26,620 K RuntimeBroker.exe             2332 Console
>   1     27,060 K chrome.exe                   10368 Console
>   1    443,000 K chrome.exe                   17136 Console
>   1     12,716 K chrome.exe                    7128 Console
>   1     13,040 K chrome.exe                   16768 Console
>   1     35,532 K chrome.exe                   24884 Console
>   1    108,768 K chrome.exe                   25512 Console
>   1    109,988 K chrome.exe                    5084 Console
>   1     70,600 K chrome.exe                    2744 Console
>   1     27,772 K chrome.exe                   25104 Console
>   1     21,664 K chrome.exe                   18768 Console
>   1     24,232 K chrome.exe                   22124 Console
>   1     25,388 K chrome.exe                    4876 Console
>   1     26,752 K chrome.exe                   15500 Console
>   1     28,364 K chrome.exe                   16460 Console
>   1     34,232 K chrome.exe                   15068 Console
>   1     76,356 K chrome.exe                   21124 Console
>   1     29,928 K chrome.exe                   21728 Console
>   1     30,764 K chrome.exe                   11536 Console
>   1     42,612 K chrome.exe                   18284 Console
>   1     80,240 K chrome.exe                   10028 Console
>   1     24,564 K chrome.exe                    1920 Console
>   1     35,168 K rundll32.exe                 20024 Console
>   1      8,128 K svchost.exe                  21760 Services
>   0      6,708 K dasHost.exe                  15740 Services
>   0      9,392 K ONENOTE.EXE                  14912 Console
>   1    396,272 K svchost.exe                   8032 Services
>   0     10,488 K svchost.exe                  23140 Services
>   0     18,808 K EXCEL.EXE                     9240 Console
>   1    160,952 K RuntimeBroker.exe            13116 Console
>   1      3,264 K dllhost.exe                  16680 Console
>   1     13,412 K FileCoAuth.exe               19088 Console
>   1     10,808 K svchost.exe                  24444 Services
>   0      7,048 K MendeleyWordPlugin.exe       16772 Console
>   1     16,380 K sppsvc.exe                    5200 Services
>   0      9,704 K WindowsInternal.Composabl     8716 Console
>   1     28,724 K chrome.exe                    9652 Console
>   1     61,908 K UpdateChecker.exe            24012 Console
>   1        128 K chrome.exe                   16752 Console
>   1     35,712 K chrome.exe                   10208 Console
>   1     23,612 K chrome.exe                    5220 Console
>   1     23,156 K chrome.exe                   13096 Console
>   1     29,356 K chrome.exe                    3872 Console
>   1     26,784 K chrome.exe                   20708 Console
>   1     62,132 K svchost.exe                  18972 Services
>   0      5,784 K ShellExperienceHost.exe      26188 Console
>   1     87,380 K SystemSettingsBroker.exe      4856 Console
>   1     33,488 K chrome.exe                   12092 Console
>   1     28,780 K WUDFHost.exe                 21076 Services
>   0      7,708 K svchost.exe                  12076 Services
>   0     10,328 K LockApp.exe                   6000 Console
>   1     23,892 K RuntimeBroker.exe            22824 Console
>   1     23,996 K svchost.exe                   6636 Services
>   0      8,204 K audiodg.exe                  21416 Services
>   0     28,576 K Spotify.exe                  24400 Console
>   1     91,004 K Spotify.exe                  13404 Console
>   1     14,500 K Spotify.exe                  21032 Console
>   1     80,472 K SpotifyWebHelper.exe          5076 Console
>   1      8,156 K Spotify.exe                  22828 Console
>   1    134,680 K svchost.exe                  13028 Services
>   0      5,376 K chrome.exe                   23276 Console
>   1     12,172 K taskhostw.exe                17432 Console
>   1     15,712 K chrome.exe                   17740 Console
>   1    113,164 K chrome.exe                   10024 Console
>   1     73,860 K chrome.exe                   18208 Console
>   1     52,572 K explorer.exe                 22148 Console
>   1     80,352 K chrome.exe                   23068 Console
>   1    283,788 K chrome.exe                   19552 Console
>   1     73,352 K chrome.exe                   18624 Console
>   1    103,424 K chrome.exe                    2268 Console
>   1     38,756 K chrome.exe                   15448 Console
>   1     38,028 K chrome.exe                   22112 Console
>   1     80,216 K chrome.exe                   26388 Console
>   1     52,880 K chrome.exe                   20340 Console
>   1     52,468 K chrome.exe                    7848 Console
>   1    179,928 K chrome.exe                     344 Console
>   1     62,024 K chrome.exe                   23500 Console
>   1     41,524 K SecHealthUI.exe               7556 Console
>   1     57,400 K dllhost.exe                  14260 Console
>   1      8,648 K smartscreen.exe              26012 Console
>   1     29,200 K chrome.exe                   25752 Console
>   1     34,168 K chrome.exe                   18548 Console
>   1     37,912 K chrome.exe                   17648 Console
>   1     68,400 K chrome.exe                   18576 Console
>   1     88,648 K MBAMService.exe              21212 Services
>   0    337,996 K mbamtray.exe                 20768 Console
>   1     37,824 K mbam.exe                      5832 Console
>   1    103,996 K chrome.exe                   22372 Console
>   1     49,788 K chrome.exe                   14228 Console
>   1     51,188 K chrome.exe                   12388 Console
>   1     86,044 K chrome.exe                   22020 Console
>   1     54,592 K chrome.exe                   21296 Console
>   1     93,064 K cmd.exe                      17708 Console
>   1      6,116 K conhost.exe                  22636 Console
>   1     18,248 K WmiPrvSE.exe                 15140 Services
>   0     11,240 K CTServiceInstaller.exe       23404 Services
>   0      5,488 K CybereasonRansomFree.exe     25580 Console
>   1      3,812 K SearchProtocolHost.exe        1584 Services
>   0      7,420 K tasklist.exe                 18264 Console
>   1      8,468 K

Comment: At a guess, perhaps RansomWare Free [is creating these files itself](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/637573/virus-creating-randomly-named-folders-not-windows-update/). This [InfoSec.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/148511) post seems to back this up.

Comment: @Anaksunaman - yes, they may be honeypot files that are especially monitored, so if something encrypts them, actions can be taken,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented above by Anaksunaman and Peter Hahndorf they are probably honeypot files.

See [windows 10 - Can you recognize this virus? - Information Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/148511/can-you-recognize-this-virus) for more information.